# Is $H$ a vector subspace of ${R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to understand vectors subspaces and came across with this exercise:

Check whether $H=\{(x,y,x)\in{R}^3 \mid x+y+2z=0 \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

I tried to solve it but I came up with this:
$\alpha*v1 + \beta*w1+\alpha*v2 + \beta*w2+2\alpha*v3 + 2\beta*w3=\alpha*v+\beta*w=0$

Is that right? Does that mean that $H$ is a subspace of ${R}^3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that to show that $H$ is a subspace, you need to test:

1. Closure under scalar multiplication: if $\vec{v} := (x, y, z) \in H$, then is $k \vec{v} = (kx, ky, kz) \in H$ for any other $k \in \mathbb{R}$? Put another way, if $x + y + 2z = 0$, then does $kx + ky + 2kz = 0$?
2. Closure under vector addition: if $\vec v_1 := (x_1, y_1, z_1) \in H$ and $\vec v_2 := (x_2, y_2, z_2) \in H$, then is $\vec v_1 + \vec v_2 = (x_1 + x_2, y_1 + y_2, z_1 + z_2) \in H$? Put another way, if $x_1 + y_1 + 2z_1 = 0$ and $x_2 + y_2 + 2 z_2 = 0$, then does $(x_1 + x_2) + (y_1 + y_2) + 2 (z_1 + z_2) = 0$?

I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Okay, this may be very trivial but how can I check those equations? Would it be a possible way to check under scalar multiplication $k(-y-2z)+ky+2kz=0$ ? If not, how can I check it?

Comment: You need to check that $kx + ky + 2kz = 0$ for arbitrary $x$, not just for some convenient value. But remember that $kx + ky + 2kz = k(x+y+2z)$, and you know by hypothesis what $x+y+2z$ is ;-)